# How to get presentation tools like windows office without windows office?

Tags: microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which office suite is the ideal alternative to MSOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139858/which-office-suite-is-the-ideal-alternative-to-msoffice)

On working with MS Office and LibreOffice I found that (as countless have) Libreoffice is not quite up to Windows' level. I would like windows Office on Ubuntu but that means using Wine, which I don't want. I tried using wine but it went a teansy bit wrong (where i have no idea). So I tend to avoid it.
Hence the question :

Is there any way I can get any program/plugin/patch/anyting-I-missed to get same functionality as MS Office in Ubuntu?

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64bit (if required).

Comment: I guess since you don't want to use wine, the only other choice is create a virtualization drive where you can use [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/products/) to emulate windows. That's the only way I know.

Comment: There is no way to eat the lunch and leave it untouched at the same time. If you need MS Office, then use MS Office.

Comment: I don't know why you don't want to use wine. I use the latest wine from the official ppa and MS Office installs and works perfectly.

Comment: By the way, did you try prezi.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibreOffice is the best office suite for Ubuntu, in my opinion.

You can use Wine to run Office, as others have said, but personally I also find the experience less than satisfying.

In addition, there are other web-based apps e.g. Google Docs' presentation program and Slide Rocket.

Ultimately though, you might do well to think a little creatively and use graphics programs such as Inkscape(+Sozi), Gimp, Blender etc. - and come to think of it why not XMind? - in tandem with LibreOffice Impress to give yourself a much more satisfying range of professional presentation options.

Note that LibreOffice 3.6 now has some fantastic wide-screen contemporary templates. This has been an area in which Impress has been particularly lacking. Sadly, it's one of these previous editions that you'll have in 12.04. A good reason to upgrade perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of functionality are you missing from Office? It's kind of tricky to answer your question without knowing.

There are alternatives to LibreOffice, but few which are as sophisticated as it is.

If you want Microsoft Office without Wine, there is a web app version of Office which you can access through [Microsoft SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com). I've not tried them myself, but as they're made by Microsoft, I would have thought they'd have similar functionality to their Windows-based counterparts.

In terms of native apps, you might want to try AbiWord - it's a nice word processor which you can install straight from the Ubuntu Software Centre.  There's also [Ease](http://www.ease-project.org), a simple piece of presentation software. It looks promising, but unfortunately hasn't been updated since 2010.

Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: What I am looking for is more variety of options and more user friendly experience(more than LibreOffice)